# How to show values in json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, filtering

Wondered if somebody could help me with some JavaScript.

I have a json file which looks similar to the one below, although this is a cut down version of the original one which is considerably larger. I'm attempting to grab some coordinates from it and use them to outline specific areas on a google map to which I set myself up a fiddle to test with:

https://jsfiddle.net/pork1977/up8rnf6d/

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "LEVEL1_COD": 1,
                "LEVEL1_NAM": "EUROPE"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                24.128105619999872,
                                34.858005329767494
                            ],
                            [
                                24.128505619999856,
                                34.808905329767484
                            ],
                            [
                                24.044605619999857,
                                34.850005329767484
                            ],
                            [
                                24.074605619999858,
                                34.868605329767476
                            ],
                            [
                                20.819105619999874,
                                80.719105329767487
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "LEVEL1_COD": 2,
                "LEVEL1_NAM": "AFRICA"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                32.954405619999847,
                                -26.058594670232509
                            ],
                            [
                                32.895205619999871,
                                -26.040794670232515
                            ],
                            [
                                32.980505619999889,
                                -25.972794670232517
                            ],
                            [
                                32.982705619999848,
                                -25.98359467023252
                            ],
                            [
                                32.954405619999847,
                                -26.058594670232509
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "LEVEL1_COD": 3,
                "LEVEL1_NAM": "AUSTRALASIA"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                169.185405619999841,
                                -52.576994670232516
                            ],
                            [
                                169.028205619999852,
                                -52.559194670232515
                            ],
                            [
                                169.000705619999877,
                                -52.507194670232515
                            ],
                            [
                                169.205205619999873,
                                -52.441394670232512
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "LEVEL1_COD": 4,
                "LEVEL1_NAM": "ASIA-TROPICAL"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                96.914105619999845,
                                -12.198094670232521
                            ],
                            [
                                96.902405619999882,
                                -12.199994670232513
                            ],
                            [
                                96.914705619999864,
                                -12.151994670232511
                            ],
                            [
                                96.924405619999874,
                                -12.182794670232511
                            ],
                            [
                                96.914105619999845,
                                -12.198094670232521
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "LEVEL1_COD": 5,
                "LEVEL1_NAM": "SOUTHERN AMERICA"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -67.212794380000133,
                                -55.893594670232517
                            ],
                            [
                                -67.246994380000132,
                                -55.894994670232514
                            ],
                            [
                                -67.41389438000013,
                                -55.832194670232518
                            ],
                            [
                                -67.246994380000132,
                                -55.828094670232517
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm attempting to filter some values on this. What I'm trying to do is get the "coordinates" when I specify a value for the LEVEL1_COD key in the filter.

I've managed to do this by running the below, and in this example it shows me the coordinates for EUROPE as this has it's LEVEL1_COD value set to 1. Note: the json variable here is using the full blown version of my snippet above.

```
var json = JSON.parse($.getJSON({'url': "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdwg/wgsrpd/master/geojson/level1.geojson", 'async': false}).responseText);

var coords = json.features.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.properties.LEVEL1_COD == "1");
})[0].geometry.coordinates

console.log(coords);
```

Console.log shows me:

> [ [ [ [ 24.128105619999872, 34.858005329767494 ], [
> 24.128505619999856, 34.808905329767484 ], [ 24.044605619999857, 34.850005329767484 ], [ 24.074605619999858, 34.868605329767476 ], [ 20.819105619999874, 80.719105329767487 ] ] ] ]

What I can't figure out, is how to change this from an 'equals' to a 'contains' type of filter.

For example, if I had a list of LEVEL1_COD values of say 1,2,5 and I wanted to filter on those values so I could see each set of coordinates, how would you go about doing that? I'd like to get the areas outlined on the map for each of these areas.

I'm sure the line which needs tweaking is:

> return (el.properties.LEVEL1_COD == "1");

But after trying all sorts of things I can't get it to return more than one set. Do you need to loop through each item to do this? or is there a smarter way? Speed is somewhat important since the json files I'll be using are quite large.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Perhaps declare a var something like `levels = [1,2,5]` and then change your filter condition to `levels.includes(el.properties.LEVEL1_COD)`

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thank you. I've created a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pork1977/2rysg5vq/274/

I think I'm probably going about it all the wrong way, I'm trying to outline areas/countries based on those values. I'm attempting to use Google maps and the script will eventually go into a larger web site where the values will end up being changed dynamically based upon user input etc.

I'll keep playing anyway, thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get more than one matching elements from the data based on the provided input(multiple values i.e., an array) `Array.some` can be used.

Below I've simulated few examples, hope this is what you are looking for

```js
let data = {type:'FeatureCollection',features:[{type:'Feature',properties:{LEVEL1_COD:1,LEVEL1_NAM:'EUROPE',},geometry:{type:'MultiPolygon',coordinates:[[[[24.128105619999872,34.858005329767494],[24.128505619999856,34.808905329767484],[24.044605619999857,34.850005329767484],[24.074605619999858,34.868605329767476],[20.819105619999874,80.719105329767487],],],],},},{type:'Feature',properties:{LEVEL1_COD:2,LEVEL1_NAM:'AFRICA',},geometry:{type:'MultiPolygon',coordinates:[[[[32.954405619999847,-26.058594670232509],[32.895205619999871,-26.040794670232515],[32.980505619999889,-25.972794670232517],[32.982705619999848,-25.98359467023252],[32.954405619999847,-26.058594670232509],],],],},},{type:'Feature',properties:{LEVEL1_COD:3,LEVEL1_NAM:'AUSTRALASIA',},geometry:{type:'MultiPolygon',coordinates:[[[[169.185405619999841,-52.576994670232516],[169.028205619999852,-52.559194670232515],[169.000705619999877,-52.507194670232515],[169.205205619999873,-52.441394670232512],],],],},},{type:'Feature',properties:{LEVEL1_COD:4,LEVEL1_NAM:'ASIA-TROPICAL',},geometry:{type:'MultiPolygon',coordinates:[[[[96.914105619999845,-12.198094670232521],[96.902405619999882,-12.199994670232513],[96.914705619999864,-12.151994670232511],[96.924405619999874,-12.182794670232511],[96.914105619999845,-12.198094670232521],],],],},},{type:'Feature',properties:{LEVEL1_COD:5,LEVEL1_NAM:'SOUTHERN AMERICA',},geometry:{type:'MultiPolygon',coordinates:[[[[-67.212794380000133,-55.893594670232517],[-67.246994380000132,-55.894994670232514],[-67.41389438000013,-55.832194670232518],[-67.246994380000132,-55.828094670232517]]]]}}]};

const getFilteredData = (data, input) =>
  data.features.filter(feature => {
    return input.some(i => i === feature.properties.LEVEL1_COD);
  });


let input = [1];
let filterdData = getFilteredData(data, input);
console.log(filterdData);

input = [1, 2, 5];
filterdData = getFilteredData(data, input);
console.log(filterdData);

input = [1, 7];
filterdData = getFilteredData(data, input);
console.log(filterdData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that Nithish, that was most helpful.

I've spent some considerable time on this today and I got to the point where I can now return the data based upon your example here, but I can't seem to write the code to form the json correctly in order to display multiple areas on the map.

I've been trying to concatenate the values but I'm obviously doing something very wrong as it works with 1 value but not more than that. I suspect the way I'm trying to do it just breaks things horribly and it's probably formatting issues.

https://jsfiddle.net/pork1977/2rysg5vq/432/

Comment: One more question, do you know if it's possible to automatically zoom the map to the boundaries of the selected areas? Is is best to ask a new question for this?

Comment: I have modified the fiddle which you've shared. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nithishg/fohquk3s/2/) is the link. Just for the example purpose I have added the marker and the info window provided by google maps itself.

Comment: Ty, all done now
Finished version (with a couple of hicups around which file to load)
https://jsfiddle.net/pork1977/okwma8pf/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are populating your mapbox. You could use the package's filter

```
this.map.setFilter('YOUR_LAYER', ['==', 'LEVEL1_COD', 'YOUR_VALUE']);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Rye, I pretty much managed to do what I needed to now with Nitihish's help above. I've just got to find a way to set the zoom now based on whatever areas are selected, which I have no idea how to do at the moment but I'll get there I'm sure.